# Send a custom response back to python code from the Node.js server, for a POST request

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, response

I am running a Python code to post some data to my Node.js server. Upon receiving the data at the server, i need the Node.js server to send a custom response back to the Python along with the status code.

I am using pure Node.js. No frameworks like Express or Hapi is used. My code works perfectly but i am not able to print the desired message.

**Part of my Python Code used to post the data**

```
import requests, json
payload = {
                     "DevId" : 'R',
                     "Sdata" : 'S',
                     "TimeS" : 'T',
                     "RSSI"  : 'U'
            }
jsonPayload=json.dumps(payload)
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}          
post_res =requests.post(url='http://localhost:5555/',data=jsonPayload, headers=headers)
print post_response
```

What i have tried at the Node.js server are.

1.

```
response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
response.end('Server has received the data')
```

**Output** :     `<Response [400]>`

2.

```
response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain','Trailer': 'Server-Message' });
response.addTrailers({ 'Server-Message': 'Ok' });
response.end();
```

**Output** :     `<Response [200]>`

3.

```
var message = 'Invalid Device ID';
response.writeHead(400, message, {'content-type' : 'text/plain'});
response.end(message);
```

**Output** :     `<Response [400]>`

I didn't get any error for the above code, so i don't know what i am doing wrong.

My desired output is, along with the status code i need to print a custom message received from the server, in the terminal i am executing the Python code.

`<Response [200]> "The server has received the message"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try printing `post_response.text` as well as `post_response` as per [requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content)

example:

server.js:

```
const http = require('http')

const server = http.createServer((req,res) => {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Server has received the message');
})

server.listen(3000, (err) => {
  if(err) {
    console.error('error');
  }

  console.log('server listening on port 3000');
})
```

response.py:

```
import requests

r = requests.post('http://localhost:3000', { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

print(str(r) + " " + r.text)
```

Comment: This works fine. I had read the Node.js documentation several times but didn't find any solution. And never thought i could find it in pythons documentation.